# FindControl not finding the correct control in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have an issue with a GridView and a HiddenField inside the GridView. I'm trying to pull some data based in the value of the HiddenField which is basically the row_id for each record but for some reason I keep getting the same data regardless of which one I select in the GridView. The code below is the one I'm using the find the HiddenField in the GridView.

Any help will be greatly appreciated it.

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow item in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (item.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            rowid = (HiddenField)(item.Cells[0].FindControl("po_id_hf"));
        }
    }

    GridView2.DataSource = View_SP.v_asn_detail_by_asn_number(Int32.Parse(rowid.Value));
    GridView2.DataBind();

    step2.Visible = false;
    step3.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: how is your markup? I think this will always get the last row value???

Answer (score 4):

What about using:

```
GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
```

to get the current updating row?

EDIT: Your code will always return the last GridViewRows, since it is iterating through the whole GridViewRows collection so at the end rowid will have the last row id in the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

I was over thinking this, below is the solutions:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
     string row_id = (((HiddenField)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("po_id_hf"))).Value);


    GridView2.DataSource = View_SP.v_asn_detail_by_asn_number(Int32.Parse(row_id));
    GridView2.DataBind();

    step2.Visible = false;
    step3.Visible = true;
}
```

Thank you guys.